# How to specify shell for vim?

Tags: vim, shell, macvim

Can I specify my shell for vim? I'm running OS X and have zsh installed via Homebrew and am using MacVim. When I type `shell` in MacVim, the shell opens up as `bash`. How can I have it open as `zsh`?

Comment: vim will by default use your system configured shell. I suspect you're running zsh somewhere in your profile or your bash profile. Try running `chsh` to change your shell on your mac.

Comment: @mkomitee I wish it _did_, and vanilla Vim, run from a terminal, does just fine with that. But straight-up, I have MacPorts' Bash set as my shell (verified with `chsh`), yet MacVim was using `/bin/sh` when I `:sh`elled out. I thought it could be some weird app security / sandboxing thing with recent versions of macOS, but here is this question **from 2011**.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add or change the following line in `~/.vimrc`:

```
set shell=/path/to/zsh
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I specify `set shell=/bin/bash` in ~/.vimrc, but when I execute `:shell` and type `echo $SHELL` output is `/bin/zsh`.

Comment: @Daniel Kats, The `SHELL` env var doesn't indicate what shell is being used; it specifies what shell to use for interactive shells.

Answer (score 7):

Not enough reputation for adding a comment, this is meant as a response to @BlackSheep comment in the accepted answer:

Despite the similar syntax, the `set shell=/bin/bash` does not apply to shell variables, but to variables that are internal to vi, so you can run a shell even if the system's shell for the active user is not a real one.

Also you can use `:set shell=/bin/bash` then `:sh` if you don't want to modify `~/.vimrc`

Comment: `:sh` works for my case.